# Azure Cognitive Service - TTS

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, text-to-speech

I just signed for free Azure account. I checked and rechecked that my Subscription ID is correct.

This code fails and the reason is:

"WebSocket upgrade failed: Authentication error (401). Please check subscription information and region name. USP state: Sending. Received audio size: 0 bytes."

Can anybody shed the light on what's going on?

```
     public static async Task Start()

     {

         var subscriptionKey = "my subscription ID is here";

         var region = "westus2"; // I live in San Diego ,CA


         var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);

         config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-AriaNeural";


        using (var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput("output.wav"))
        {
            using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, audioConfig))
            {
                string inputText = "Hello, this is a sample text to be converted to speech. It is not long, but hopefully it is of a great quality" +

                                   "since it is generating using Azure SDK. Have a nice day!";

                try
                {
                    using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputText))
                    {
                        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"The text has been converted to speech and saved as output.wav");
                        }
                        else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                        {
                            var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");
                            if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                            }
                        }
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using Speech service in Azure I converted text-to-speech and saved as output.wav.

- Create a [Speech Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

[image]

- Get the [region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75822762/azure-function-to-query-postgres-db-which-can-be-accessed-via-ssh-creating-ssh-t) and key form the [Speech resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKQ5n.png).

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace TextToSpeech
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string subscriptionKey = "Your Speech service subscriptionKey";
            string region = "your Speech service Location/Region";
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
            config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-AriaNeural";
            string inputText = "Hello, here is a sample text that will be said aloud.";
            using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
            {
                using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputText))
                {
                    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                    {
                      using (var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result))
                        {
                            await audioDataStream.SaveToWaveFileAsync("output.wav");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"After being read out, the text was saved as output. wav");
                    }
                    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");
                        if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MSFT fails to name the keys correctly. Most of the people that had this problem, myself included, though that they need to use Azure Subscription Key... which is incorrect.
One of 2 keys generated by Azure Cognitive Services is the right key to use!